# How to make the NSMenuItem's position just below New Folder item in FinderSync?

Tags: swift, macos, finder, nsmenuitem, findersync

I override the `menu(for menuKind: FIMenuKind)` shows in the following:

```swift
override func menu(for menuKind: FIMenuKind) -> NSMenu {
    let menu = NSMenu(title: "")
    let menuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "❤️", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
    menuItem.submenu = NSMenu(title: "")
        
    let watchMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "⌚️", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
    menuItem.submenu?.items.append(watchMenuItem)

    let lightMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
    menuItem.submenu?.items.append(lightMenuItem)

    menu.addItem(menuItem)
        
    return menu
}
```

Currently the two custom NSMenuItems appear in the bottom of the Finder menu, shows in the following photo:
[image]

I want my custom NSMenuItem appear just below the `New Folder` button, how can I do that?

Comment: You can't, the Finder will add the extensions menu items wherever it wants.